# jdbc postgresql transaction error occurred

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, nullpointerexception

```
public class JDBC {

static Connection con;
static Statement stmt;

public static void main(String argv[]){

connect();
 con.setAutoCommit(false);

     // Statement s=  conn.createStatement();

       con.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);

        //set a Savepoint


        System.out.println("savepoint1");
        String SQL = "INSERT INTO Flight VALUES (1000, '22/7/2013', 'LGW', 'MAN', 10,40)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);

        Savepoint savepoint1 = conn.setSavepoint("Savepoint1");


        String SQL2 = "UPDATE Flight SET flightid = 500 WHERE Flightid = 1000";
        stmt.executeUpdate(SQL2);

        con.rollback(savepoint1);


        con.commit();
        System.out.println("end");
}



static void connect() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, DataSourceException {
    try {
        // load database driver driver

        Class.forName(DataSource.getClassName());

        // connect to database from a given URL with a given username and
        // password

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DataSource.getURL(), DataSource.getUserName(), DataSource.getPassword());

        // create an SQL statement object
        stmt = con.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        con = null;
        stmt = null;
        throw (se);
    }
    }       
   }
}
```

hello, im trying to understand how to use savepoint. but every time i run the program..it came out the null pointer exception which said the error is occur in the con.setautocommit(false);

any suggestion will appreciate....

Comment: Are you sure that your `con` is not null? I mean have you initialized it?

Comment: Nothing to be sure about, that's the problem.... Connection is not properly initialized.

Comment: A NPE on `con.setautocommit(false);` means that `con` is null. You cannot expect to trying to understand savepoints before understanding the basics of establishing a connection.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you have not properly initialized your `Connection con` variable.
You are not showing that part of the code, so we cannot help you more.